# MariaDB MySQL - SQL Error (1049): Unknown database 'unnamed' when copying database files to new server

Tags: mariadb

I am getting an error after copying database files to new server. I copied all of the server files as well. Windows 10 Pro. MariaDB  10.3.10-MariaDB

The Error:
SQL Error (1049): Unknown database ‘unnamed’

Comment: Did you copy *all* of the entire data directory? What version was it running? What is in the mariadb error log? Why are you using such an old [10.3 version](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-103-series/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

1. I copied ONLY the database folder I needed. (EG:  mysql\data\DATABASE)
2. I copied ibdata1 file ONLY